# Concatenation String in shell

Tags: shell

I have this shell line to concatenate 2 string:

```
 new_group="second result is: ${result},\"${policyActivite}_${policyApplication}\""

echo "result is: ${new_group}"
```

The result:

```
result is: "Team","Application_Team"
```

How can change the result to: result is: `"Team, Application_Team"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
echo "$new_group"  | sed 's/"//g;s/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/'
```

The first statement is removing all double quotes. The second one add double at the start and the end of the line.

Alternatively, if you want to replace `","` with `,`, use this sed command: `sed 's/","/, /g'`

Comment: it's not working, because I don't have a file, Team1, Team22,... are the string

Comment: @vero I don't understand. Where do you see a file in this command?